# jQuery get an elements position when it has been animated using css3 animations

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-isotope, css-animations

If you use CSS3 animations to position stuff on the screen for an element that is position relative

```
-moz-transform: translate(125px, 5px);
```

When you ask for the items position using javascript it will report that the item is still

```
top:0
left:0
```

For example have a look at the position of elements in this example that uses jQuery Isotope plugin:

http://isotope.metafizzy.co/demos/basic.html

Will I have to use jQuery css() method like this? I don't even know if that will work!

```
$(element).css('-moz-transform')
```

UPDATE:

I have posted an example of this on JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/uQtur/3/

JS

```
var elements = $('.element').each(function(i, e){
    var el = $(this);
    var position = el.position();
    var offset = el.offset();

    console.log('position', position);
    console.log('offset', offset);

    var positionLeft = window.getComputedStyle(el.get(0), null).getPropertyValue('left');
    var positionTop = window.getComputedStyle(el.get(0), null).getPropertyValue('top');

    console.log('computed position left', positionLeft);
    console.log('computed position top', positionTop);  

    var transform = el.css('-moz-transform');
    console.log(transform);

    // > matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 340px, 10px)
});
```

HTML

```
<div id='container'>
    <div class='element' style='left: 0px; top: 0px; -moz-transform: translate(10px, 10px);'>
        H
    </div>
    <div class='element' style='left: 0px; top: 0px; -moz-transform: translate(120px, 10px);'>
        He
    </div>
    <div class='element' style='left: 0px; top: 0px; -moz-transform: translate(230px, 10px);'>
        He
    </div>
    <div class='element' style='left: 0px; top: 0px; -moz-transform: translate(340px, 10px);'>
        He
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post a demo (perhaps at [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)) for us to play with to help answer your question?

Comment: I'll try, at the minute though all I'm getting is a '502: bad gateway' error (not your fault, obviously; just JS Fiddle being weighed under, at a guess...).

Comment: I tried using getComputedStyle... doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

In the options set `itemPositionDataEnabled: true`. Then you get the values with `.data('isotope-item-position')`. See http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/options.html#itempositiondataenabled

`.offset()` and `getComputedStyle` will not work since Isotope utilizes CSS3 transforms for positioning.  Another solution is to disable transforms, with `transformsEnabled: false`.

Comment: Awesome thanks @desandro I can't believe I missed that in the docs, I have been poring over them for the last couple weeks! Yay now I will be able to calculate the position so I can show some popovers relative to the isotope items and then I can turn css animations back on :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's offset function, which will give you the relative position.  If you need the exact position, you can then take the exact position of the container element.  So, your code might look like:

```
var off = $("div.element[data-symbol='Ca']").offset();
var containPos = $("#container").position();

var totalTop = off.top + containPos.top;
var totalLeft = off.left + containPos.left;

console.log(totalTop);
console.log(totalLeft);
```

Comment: Sorry, but you are wrong. Offset is top:0 and left:0 Checkout the proof http://jsfiddle.net/uQtur/3/

Comment: Very interesting - I was getting positive results on the isotope page.  Sorry for the bad info!

Comment: This method worked for me, admittedly not using 'isotope' but using offset and position (for working out google map cell position) worked. Thanks